# Finding master page control from within iFrame

Tags: asp.net, master-pages

**Scenario:**

I have one main master page say *MasterPage1*. In that master page I have a splitter. In that splitter there is an **iframe**. Within that *iframe* we load another master page say "*MasterPage2*". In  *MasterPage2* we load a page on which different User Controls are rendered.

**Problem:**

Now I want to find a control on *MasterPage1* from my User Control loaded on the page in *MasterPage2*.

Please help....

Answer (score 0):

**Problem To your Scenario:**

masterpages and content pages are rendered as a single object, thus the page class is able to **reference** every element found in both the objects(master and content page). When you are rendering an iframe the iframe content is requested by client hence no **reference exists**. **so it is not possible to reference each other on server.**

**Solution to the problem**

From above you must have realized  all the problem is the **reference** , so you will have to hack inti it. the simplest way I can think is to use querystring.
call the iframe page with querystring containing a identifier to the masterpage like mpage=mpage1,mpage=mpage2 etc.
Now in masterpage2 request the querystring to find which masterpage is applied and proceed. This way you will have little relaxaction because masterpage1 content cannot be changed but masterpage2 can be.

Now you will need to work more to what you need. Proceed only if this is the only way to solve the real problem(I think the problem is not masterpage but the solution to the problem that is making you to do these weired things).
Well for that you will have to use javascript and handlers which will render and return the rendered usercontrol. But i seriously say not to use this setup in production and find other alternative by changing your code to use usercontrol instead of iframe.